# Karma, the test doesn't run

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-runner, angular-scenario

this is what my karma code looks like ..

```
describe('E2E: Testing Controllers', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser().navigateTo('/dashboard/');
  });

  it('should have a working home page controller that applies the leads to scope', function() {
    browser().navigateTo('#/');
    expect(browser().location().path()).toBe("/");
    expect(element('.shoutbox').html());
  });
});
```

the karma is stuck at

```
browser navigate to '/dashboard/'
```

i am not sure what could be wrong here.

here is my karma config

```
var sharedConfig = require('./karma.shared.conf');

module.exports = function(config) {
  var conf = sharedConfig();

  conf.files = conf.files.concat([
    //test files
    './tests/e2e/**/*.js'
  ]);

  conf.proxies = {
    '/': 'http://localhost:8080/'
  };

  conf.urlRoot = '/__e2e/';

  conf.frameworks = ['ng-scenario'];

  config.set(conf);
};
```

where could i be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Which browser you are using, because I don't see any config e.g. `'browsers: ['Chrome']'`?

Please make a sure that you have running application at configured address in `proxies`.

Have you installed required plugins, such as:

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher

or

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-scenario

And if your browser are starting, take a look at the javascript console if there are some errors.

Maybe you need to include more files to your karma.conf e.g:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            'vendor/angular/angular.js', 'vendor/angular/angular-resource.js', 'vendor/angular/angular-mocks.js', 'test/e2e.*.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/e2e/**/*.js',
            'src/**/*.html'
        ]
```

Why you use `browser().navigateTo('');` in `beforeEach()` and again in `it()`?

And what you want to achieve with this expect: `expect(element('.shoutbox').html());`?

Have a look at [ng-scenario syntax](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) and consider using [Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor).